# html generated by theme exist but doesnt appear in browser

Tags: plugins, menus, html

I am using [this](https://responsive.menu/docs/advanced-setup/shortcode/) plugin, and I put

> wp_head() and wp_footer() calls in my header.php and footer.php files
>   respectively

just like the site said. I allowed in configurations to use shortcode (just like the site said) and also put the code

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[responsive_menu]'); ?>
```

in my `page-however.php`, but when I refresh the browser, the menu is not appearing. When I inspect my site code, it appear just like this:

[image]

the `button` and `div id` code are generated by the `plugin`, however, the code of it is transparent. I think that means that something is wrong with it. But what? I dont know what to do here, and I didnt find here some question like this.

Comment: Hi, it seems like the elements are hidden. Check for a style property of `display:none` in the right panel after selecting these 2 elements.

Comment: thanks a lot! answer this and i'll give you the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your elements are hidden by a style property.

Click on your elements and see if there is a `display:none` style property in the right panel, and simply change it to `display:inline`, `display:inline-block` or `display:block` to make it visible.